# How can I display the current radio value with onchange functions to reflect the correct results on a different HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html

Can you help me? I want to make an Accuracy Quiz in which after you click on submit 
it will get your answer and how much time in seconds it took you to complete the quiz & compare it to the array of data in function and display it on a different HTML Page.

I use `onchange="handleInput(this);"` & <`form action="Results.html">` to show results on different page. I am new to Javascript.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

**Sample Results Display**

> Oops! You got 3 answers wrong!
>
> Incorrect answers: 2, 4, 5
>
> You took 17 seconds to complete the quiz. With 5 answers wrong that
>   equates to 65 errors per hour! Data Accuracy Answer Key
>
> There are two exact matches: 1 and 3. All others are not a match.
>   Please keep in mind that 90 seconds is the average time it takes to
>   finish the quiz.

**Here's my code so far:**

```
<html>
<title>Accuracy Proofing</title>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
startday = new Date();
clockStart = startday.getTime();
function initStopwatch() { 
var myTime = new Date(); 
var timeNow = myTime.getTime();  
var timeDiff = timeNow - clockStart; 
this.diffSecs = timeDiff/1000; 
return(this.diffSecs); 
} 
var secStop=setInterval(function(){getSecs()},1000);
function getSecs() { 
var mySecs = initStopwatch(); 
var mySecs1 = ""+mySecs;
mySecs1= mySecs1.substring(0,mySecs1.indexOf(".")) + " secs."; 
document.forms[0].elapsed_time.value = mySecs1;
document.getElementById('Timer').innerHTML = 'Elapsed time: ' + mySecs1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=initStopwatch;
window.setTimeout('getSecs()',1000); 
}
</script>

</head>

<body class="quiz-container" onLoad="window.setTimeout('getSecs()',1)">
<div class="quiz-container-inner"
        <h3>Accuracy Quiz</h3>
        <p class="overview">Compare each pair below. If the numbers, letters, and punctuation are the same, put a check in the "Same" column. If they are different, put a check in the "Different" column.</p>


        <div class="box-callout">
        <form action="Results.html" method="post" class="products" target="_top">
            <input type="hidden" name="elapsed_time" id="elapsed_time" value="0">
        <!-- Table markup-->

        <div id="Timer" name="Timer"></div>

        <table id="hor-zebra" summary="Employee Pay Sheet">

        <!-- Table header -->
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col">Correct</th>
                <th scope="col">Same</th>
                <th scope="col">Different</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">Copy</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- Table footer -->
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
            <td scope="col"></td>
            <td scope="col">Correct</td>
            <td scope="col">Same</td>
            <td scope="col">Different</td>
            <td scope="col"></td>
            <td scope="col">Copy</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>


        <!-- Table body -->
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td><span class="number">1.</span></td>
                <td><span class="times">November 16, 2005</span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="1" value="s" name="Field1" id="Field1_1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="2" value="d" name="Field1" id="Field1_2">               
                </td>
                <td><span class="number">1.</span></td>
                <td><span class="courier">Novenber 16, 2005</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="number">2.</span></td>
                <td><span class="times">CITIMORTGAGE, INC.</span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="1" value="s" name="Field2" id="Field2_1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="2" value="d" name="Field2" id="Field2_2">               
                </td>
                <td><span class="number">2.</span></td>
                <td><span class="times-tight">CITIMORGAGE, INC.</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td><span class="number">3.</span></td>
                <td><span class="times">ALICIA CARILLO</span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="1" value="s" name="Field3" id="Field3_1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="2" value="d" name="Field3" id="Field3_2">               
                </td>
                <td><span class="number">3.</span></td>
                <td><span class="times">Alcia Carillo</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="number">4.</span></td>
                <td><span class="times">45 Nortwesterly</span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="1" value="s" name="Field4" id="Field4_1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="2" value="d" name="Field4" id="Field4_2">               
                </td>
                <td><span class="number">4.</span></td>
                <td><span class="arial">45 Nortwesterley</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td><span class="number">5.</span></td>
                <td><span class="times">HUSBAND AND WIFE</span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="1" value="s" name="Field5" id="Field5_1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="2" value="d" name="Field5" id="Field5_2">               
                </td>
                <td><span class="number">5.</span></td>
                <td><span class="times">HUSBAND AND WIFE</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="number">6.</span></td>
                <td><span class="times">AMERICAHOMEKEY, INC.</span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="1" value="s" name="Field6" id="Field6_1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="2" value="d" name="Field6" id="Field6_2">               
                </td>
                <td><span class="number">6.</span></td>
                <td><span class="arial">AMERICAHOMKEY, INC.</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        </table>

    <div class="pad">
<input type="Submit" value="Show Me the Results." class="large brown awesome">
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    createTimer();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My web is in local it is not hosted to any webserver I just want to make it run locally. So that's why I can't use any server-side scripting...

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET method of form instead of POST and then parse the url for parameters. (Url stored in window.location)

Comment: Can you give a sample using `Get Method` of form and then parse the usl for parameters. `(Url stored in window.location)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not displaying the elapsed time to the end user, a cleaner way to handle it would be to compute it just once in an onsubmit handler for the form:

```
<script>
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
function saveElapsedTime( field) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var elapsed = now - startTime;
  field.value = elapsed;
  return true;
}
</script>

<form ... onsubmit='saveElapsedTime( this.elapsed_time);'>
    <input type='hidden' name='elapsed_time' id='elapsed_time' value='unknown'>
    ...
</form>
```

As for processing the results and displaying it on another page, you'd either need some server support to receive the form data, or you'd need to change the form to use `method='get'` and access the resulting data from JavaScript on the new page by parsing `window.location.search`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @scottb

can you give more example to use `method='get'` and access the resulting data from JavaScript on the new page by parsing `window.location.search`

Comment: This function will build a hash of the parameters passed:
`
    function getParameters() {
        var params = window.location.hash.substring(1).split(/&/);
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var p = params[i].split(/=/, 2);
            result[p[0]] = p[1];
        }
        return result;
    }`